# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(java.nio.Buffer)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-activity, bitmap

I have a `ImageView` I am getting bitmap out of that, and then use `copyPixelstoBuffer` and I am copying it to `buffer_temp`, now I want to use reverse algorithm to again convert it to another bitmap and from that bitmap to `ImageView2`,

what exactly I am doing is Copying an Image in `ImageView` using `Buffer` and `Pasting` it onto another `Imageview` using `Buffer`, but while Copying `copyPixelsFromBuffer` always throw

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(java.nio.Buffer)' on a null object reference.
```

Dont know why, Need help,

```
try {
                Buffer bfr = null;
                iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.olx);
                BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) iv1.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
                int bytes=bitmap.getByteCount();
                ByteBuffer buffer_temp= ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);
                bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer_temp);
                System.out.println("Values are "+ bitmap.getAllocationByteCount());

                Bitmap btmp=null;

                //btmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer_temp);


                if(buffer_temp==null)
                 return;

                buffer_temp.rewind();

                btmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer_temp);


                if(buffer_temp==null)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }



            } catch (NotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: did you initialize btmp?

Comment: use a debugger and check the contents of your buffer_temp after buffer_temp.rewind() this error is only possible when either buffer_temp is null or btmp is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*btmp* is ***null***.
There is no way that by using *the attached code*.Then, the value of btmp would be *anything*. But it's *null*!

If you want to clone Bitmap the use [create](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)) method or any other of that sort.

```
Bitmap btmp = Bitmap.create(drawable.getBitmap());
```

Comment: yes, btmp is null, because I want a new bitmap into ImageView2

Comment: Paste way more code. You have serious issue back there.

Comment: so what should I do, because I want to use new Bitmap object

Comment: its the same exception which I have described, you can go ahead and do that, take two ImageView and one button, and try the above code snippet, it keeps crashing

Comment: If the code above throws then you dont have any Bitmap at the first place

Comment: Yes, I do have, and I checked whether is it null or not,  can't you see the second line   iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.olx); I am getting drawable ->> bitmap ->> buffer

Answer (score 2):

"yes, btmp is null"

But, you trying to invoke method call on it:

`btmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer_temp); // <- here`

That not going to work. You should initialize `btmp` before using it.

**Update:**

Init it like this:

```
...
System.out.println("Values are "+ bitmap.getAllocationByteCount());

// here's the initialization
Bitmap btmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getConfig());

buffer_temp.rewind();

// now you can call copyPixelsFromBuffer() on btmp
btmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer_temp);
...
```